# Create an aggregate checksum of a column

Tags: sql, mysql, checksum

I want to compute a checksum of all of the values of a column in aggregate.

In other words, I want to do some equivalent of

```
md5(group_concat(some_column))
```

The problem with this approach is:

1. It's inefficient. It has to concat all of the values of the column as a string in some temporary storage before passing it to the md5 function
2. group_concat has a max length of 1024, after which everything else will be truncated.

(In case you're wondering, you can ensure that the concat of the values is in a consistent order, however, as believe it or not group_concat() accepts an order by clause within it, e.g. `group_concat(some_column order by some_column)`)

MySQL offers the nonstandard bitwise aggregate functions BIT_AND(), BIT_OR() and BIT_XOR() which I presume would be useful for this problem. The column is numeric in this case but I would be interested to know if there was a way to do it with string columns.

For this particular application, the checksum does not have to be cryptologically safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you might as well use `crc32` instead of `md5` if you don't care about cryptographic strength.  I think this:

```
select sum(crc32(some_column)) from some_table;
```

would work on strings.  It might be inefficient as perhaps MySQL would create a temporary table (especially if you added an `order by`).

Comment: `SUM()` Is not the right thing to use here, as two different checksums could sum to the same value quite easily

Comment: How do you avoid numeric overflow with this approach?

Answer (score 10):

The following query is used in Percona's Mysql Table Checksumming tool. Its a little tough to understand, but essentially it `CRC32`s the column (or a bunch of columns concatted) for every row, then `XOR`s them all together using the `BIT_XOR` group function. If one crc hash is different, the result of `XOR`ing everything will also be different. This happens in fixed memory, so you can checksum arbitrarily large tables.

`SELECT CONV(BIT_XOR(CAST(CRC32(column) AS UNSIGNED)), 10, 16)`

One thing to keep in mind though that this does not prevent possible collisions, and `CRC32` is a pretty weak function by today's standards. A nicer hashing function would be something like the `FNV_64`. It would be very unlikely to have two hashes which complement each other when `XOR`ed together.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  crc
FROM
(
  SELECT @r := MD5(CONCAT(some_column, @r)) AS crc,
         @c := @c + 1 AS cnt
  FROM
    (
    SELECT @r := '', @c := 0
    ) rc,
    (
    SELECT some_column
    FROM mytable
    WHERE condition = TRUE
    ORDER BY
      other_column
    ) k
) ci
WHERE cnt = @c
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column is numeric, you could do this:

```
SELECT BIT_XOR(mycolumn) + SUM(mycolumn)
```

Of course this is easy to defeat, but it will include all the bits in the column.