# mysql Averaging varchar column

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

We have same table in two different DBs
(Table structure: PK(Long), X(VarChar), Version(int)),
want to compare those two and see either they are in sync or not.
X - holds String, not numeric values.

We don't want to compare record by record. We thought of comparing `Avg(Pk)` and `Avg(X)` with the other tables `Avg(Pk)` and `Avg(X)` - if both are matching - we assume it is proper and proceed. I know some scenarios it fails, its ok as we do repeatedly this - we believe it will catch next time.

But when I tried

```
select avg(pk), avg(X) from TEST_varchar20
```

It shows warning

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

and does not give correct value.

Is it possible to use `Avg()` for Varchar or any other solution.

Comment: If the column `X` contains only numeric data then why not make it a numeric type?

Comment: This might be useful in highlighting alternative checksumming approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591234/create-an-aggregate-checksum-of-a-column

Comment: How exactly do you calculate the average of foo and bar?

Comment: This error means that some of the `x` values are not numbers. They're ignored when calculating the average, but cause this warning.

Comment: You can use `AVG()` with VARCHAR, as long as all the values look like numbers. It will automatically parse them and calculate the average. But if any of the values are not numeric, you get this warning.

Comment: You cannot average strings. There is no average value for 'house' + 'cat' and 'journey'. What you can do is get a number for the string (a hash value) with [CRC32](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_crc32) and build an average on these numbers: `select avg(num), avg(crc32(str)) from mytable`

Answer (score 1):

I guess i got the answer - still going thru it :

> select  CONV(BIT_XOR(CAST(CRC32(PK) AS UNSIGNED)), 10, 16),
> CONV(BIT_XOR(CAST(CRC32(X) AS UNSIGNED)), 10, 16)  from TEST_varchar20
> ;

Source [Create an aggregate checksum of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591234/create-an-aggregate-checksum-of-a-column)

Comment: If this is just a copy of another answer, the question should be closed as a duplicate.